# redis python psubscribe to event with callback, without calling .listen()

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I'm trying to subscribe to keyspace event in redis using python. I hope to NOT use the for-loop with `.listen()` after calling `.psubscribe()`. Is this possible?

I have enabled all keyspace events with `KEA`.

```
def subscribe(self, key, handler):

        # this function never gets called, if I don't add the for-loop with listen() below
        def event_handler(msg):
            print('Handler', msg)

        redis_server = StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
        pubsub = redis_server.pubsub()
        subscribe_key = '*'
        pubsub.psubscribe(**{subscribe_key: event_handler})

        # without the following for-loop with listen, the callback never fires. I hope to get rid of this.
        for item in pubsub.listen():
            pass
```

Answer (score 12):

#### Using `redis` module threads

A good alternative would be using [`redis.client.PubSub.run_in_thread`](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/redis/client.html#PubSub.run_in_thread) method.

```py
def subscribe(self, key, handler):
    def event_handler(msg):
        print('Handler', msg)

    redis_server = StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
    pubsub = redis_server.pubsub()
    subscribe_key = '*'
    pubsub.psubscribe(**{subscribe_key: event_handler})

    pubsub.run_in_thread(sleep_time=.01)
```

There is a good step-by-step explanation [here](https://tech.webinterpret.com/redis-notifications-python/).

#### Using `asyncio` (`aioredis`)

This code can be updated for an `asyncio` version, using `aioredis` Pub/Sub support. [Here](https://aioredis.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.0/mpsc.html) is the doc and an example.